# Angular Resolver does not hit API when reloading the page?

Tags: angular, angular-resolver

I've used resolver for one of my component. when navigate from component to route it works fine. but when I reload the page it does not hit API. it gives me the uncaught error.

**This my list**
[image]

**when i click the button it goes to this route**
[image]

**but when I reload the page (above image URL) it gives me uncaught error. 401**

[image]

Here is my code
company.resolver.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CompanyResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(
    private companyService: CompanyService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
 ) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | any  {
    return this.companyService.fetchCompanyById(route.params['id'])
  }
}
```

company.services.ts

```
fetchCompanyById(id: number) {
    return this.http
      .get(environment.apiUrl + 'company/getCompanyById/' + id)
  }
```

company-edit.component.ts

```
model: any = {};
 ngOnInit(): void {
      this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data:any) => {
        var a = data;
         console.log(a.data)
         this.model = {...a.data}
      })
    }
```

can any one help me about this issue or give suggestion whats going wrong and what to do. i would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if auth token is sent on that get call after refresh? It seems that endpoint requires authentication.

Comment: I have a token interceptor which authenticate token whenever I sent request.so token is not an issue. i tried something else like i wrap the resolver code inside setTimeOut. after that API hit properly this error doesn't occur but it creates another issue, which take time to load the data. within this time template is loaded. But this does not solve my actual business requirement

Answer (score 0):

after 5 hours study I found the solution. actual I download a UI template when i stared the project. now i found that in app.routing.module, they set value `initialNavigation` to `enableBlocking`. I just comment that and it is working fine.

app.routing.module.ts

```
  @NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
      //initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking',
      
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```